# How to create jumbotrons dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am loading articles of a database via AJAX and want to show them in a jumbotron each, which is created dynamically.

How can I achieve this?

Do I have to write the html code in a js variable and then append this into a container, 
or is there a better way like creating one jumbotron in the html file and "clone" this with other content?

Comment: So, you know how to achieve it.....what you are trying to ask is about best practices, am i right?

Comment: oh yea, kinda^^ i just wanted to know if there is another way to achieve the danyamic creation, because i dont really like to write the html code in the js file.. or is it the only way?

Comment: Are you using a particular js library? Like AngularJS or jQuery? Or are you using pure javascript? I see the jQuery tag now - so you're just using that then? I'd suggest jQuery templates if so: http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2010/11/30/an-introduction-to-jquery-templates

Comment: yes i am using jQuery only. But your link looks interesting!
Thank you therefore! never read of such a template before :D